# Explanation of sql query : Rank and partition oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, rank, window-functions

I am working with oracle database and is stuck at this query, I am not comprehending how this is working, i have removed all the unnecssesary information and the query has come down to this:

```
 select RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY A_pk ORDER BY B_pk DESC) as column from Table_C
```

Can some one explain how is this working?

Comment: This tutorial explains window functions quite nicely: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: i am working with oracle db , wil the concepts from postgresql apply to  oracle too ? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Yes, it is ANSI SQL 99 standard functions

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have the following table:

```
SELECT *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2) AS [ROW_NUMBER],
       RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2) [RANK],
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2) [DENSE_RANK]
FROM SomeTable

col1    col2  |  ROW_NUMBER RANK    DENSE_RANK
1       1     |  1          1       1
1       1     |  2          1       1
1       5     |  3          3       2
1       5     |  4          3       2
1       9     |  5          5       3
1       9     |  6          5       3
2       1     |  1          1       1
2       1     |  2          1       1
2       1     |  3          1       1
2       3     |  4          4       2
2       3     |  5          4       2
```

**ROW_NUMBER:**
These are `window ranking` functions. This means that when you partition by some column function works in the window of that partition. Imagine it like:

```
col1    col2
/*------*\
|1      1|
|1      1|
|1      5|  <--window 1
|1      5|
|1      9|
|1      9|
\*------*/

/*------*\
|2      1|
|2      1|
|2      1|  <--another window 2
|2      3|
|2      3|
\*------*/
```

When window changes everything resets! So for `ROW_NUMBER` you are ordering by `col2` and assign incremental number by that order. When window changes function resets and begins from `1`.

**RANK:**

This function will calculate count of rows where value of `col2` is less then value of `col2` in current row plus 1. For example in `window 1` for row with `col2 = 5` there are 2 rows with `col2 = 1`, so `2 + 1 = 3`. For row with `col2 = 9` there are 4 rows, so `4 + 1 = 5`.

**DENSE_RANK:**

It is the same as `RANK` but it counts preceding **DISTINCT** values! For example for row with `col2 = 9` there are 2 distinct values of `col2 = 1 and 5` so `2 + 1 = 3`

Answer (score 0):

1. Partition the table into "windows" based on values in the column `A_pk`:

   ```
    A_pk     |  B_pk
   develop   |    11
   develop   |     7
   develop   |     9
   develop   |     8
   develop   |    10
   *** window ***
   personnel |     5
   personnel |     2
   *** window ***
   sales     |     3
   sales     |     1
   sales     |     4
   ```
2. Order each "window" by `B_pk desc`:

   ```
    A_pk     |  B_pk
   develop   |    11
   develop   |    10
   develop   |     9
   develop   |     8
   develop   |     7
   *** window ***
   personnel |     5
   personnel |     2
   *** window ***
   sales     |     4
   sales     |     3
   sales     |     1
   ```
3. return the rank of each row (the "place" it's in), by window:

   ```
   1
   2
   3
   4 
   5
   *** window ***
   1
   2
   *** window ***
   1
   2
   3
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand with this simple query on the sample EMP table in SCOTT schema:

```
SQL> SELECT empno,
  2    deptno,
  3    sal,
  4    rank() over(partition BY deptno order by sal) rn
  5  FROM emp;

     EMPNO     DEPTNO        SAL         RN
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7934         10       1300          1
      7782         10       2450          2
      7839         10       5000          3
      7369         20        800          1
      7876         20       1100          2
      7566         20       2975          3
      7788         20       3000          4
      7902         20       3000          4
      7900         30        950          1
      7654         30       1250          2
      7521         30       1250          2
      7844         30       1500          4
      7499         30       1600          5
      7698         30       2850          6

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**RANK** function is a built in analytic function which is used to rank a record within a group of rows. The **PARTITION BY** clause in the window is what groups the rows, and the **ORDER BY** clause tells how to rank, i.e. which row in each group will hold the 1st rank and then assign next rank to the next rows in that order.

- GROUP
- SORT
- Assign rank

So, in above example, the rows are **grouped by department**, and **ordered by salary**. In each group, the rank is assigned starting from the lowest salary(ascending order). When there is a tie, the rank is not incremented, however, the immediate next row with change in value will not have consecutive sequence. And that's what happened here:

```
7654         30       1250          2
7521         30       1250          2
7844         30       1500          4
```

The rank is not consecutive because there is a tie between two rows with salary `1250`. To keep the sequence consecutive, you need to use **DENSE_RANK**.